# User authentication and re-direct using ajax

Tags: ajax, express

Guys I am using express js as my server.
Let me walk you through the code first.

Initially, on the home page of my website the user provides the login details on the **input form**. I used ajax to send these details(email, password) to the server. On the server-side, 2 things can happen 1. the login details are correct in which case the user should be taken to the inner page of the website. 2. the login details are not correct in which case the user sees the error message below the respective textbox(eg: Your password is incorrect).

The second part was easy. My problem is with the first part. How can I send the HTML file to the client if it is an ajax post request

here is my server-side code

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  //this is home page
  res.render("index");
});

app.post("/auth", (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body);
  const userEmail = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  usersInstance.checkUser(userEmail, password, (err, userExists) => { // this is database method.
    console.log(err, userExists);
    if (userExists) res.render('foods.ejs');
    else res.send("user does not exist");
  });
});
```

here is my client-side **AJAX** code

```
$("form").submit((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // alert("submit is clicked");
  const emailId = document.querySelector("#email").value;
  const password = document.querySelector("#password").value;
  $.ajax({
    url: "/auth",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      email: emailId,
      password: password,
    },
    success: (res) => {
      if (res == "user exists") {
        // how to display foods.ejs page in this situation?
      }
    },
    error: (err) => {
      alert("failed");
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is, how to handle this line of code properly:

```
    if (userExists) res.render('foods.ejs');
```

This depends on how do you handle routing.

1. In case you are using some client side routing (for example React router) then, your nodejs server should act only as an API endpoint (most of the time only return JSON)
2. In this case, I guess you are using express routing as a router, and when people login successfully, it would render `foods.ejs`

The problem is, this is Ajax call, so your client-side does not know how to render this response after finishing the AJAX.

The proper way should be, instead of using Ajax, just use normal form with POST request, and let the server decide what to do, instead of handle it in client

- if login succeeded, render `foods.ejs` (use your same code)
- if login fails, render `login.ejs` with some data (I assume your login UI is in `login.ejs`)

```
if (userExists) res.render('foods.ejs');
else res.render('login.ejs', {login: 'fail', message: 'user does not exist'};
```

3. Let say, you really want to use AJAX in this case (I don't know, for look and feel, may be), there is a way to do so:

```
if (userExists) res.status(200).send("user exists");

...

// new route:
app.get('/food', (req, res) => {
  //handle authentication check before rendering

  res.render('food.ejs');
})
```

And in your Ajax:

```
...
success: (res) => {
      if (res == "user exists") {
         location.href = "http://{your-domain}/food"
      }
    },
...
```

If you choose to go by this approach (i don't like this way, too troublesome, and the code is not clean), you need to handle authentication properly - like saving username in express session, or using some Token based approach to handle it (JWT, Oauth...), because anyone who type this on browser, can jump to `food.ejs`: http://{your-domain}/food

Comment: Yes, that is very much true. I think it is better to remove ajax cause anyone can access food.ejs file in the URL. I thought there is a workaround kind of thing